# Can't locate <option> tags in page source

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In the following turkish encoded web page, when viewing the source, I can't see the `<option>` tags that show the dates. I need it because of scraping with BeautifulSoup.

http://millipiyango.gov.tr/sonuclar/_cs_sayisal.php

Here is my python code:

```
def fetchDates(product):
    Form = product.find('form', attrs = {'id':'form'})
    Select = Form.find('select',attrs={'name':'tarihList'})
    for element in Select(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
        element.extract() #to eliminate comment outs (just tried, didn't useful)
    print(Form.prettify()) #prints only <select bla bla></select>

    for option in Select.find_all('option'): #prints nothing
        print('value: %s, text: %s',format(option['value'], option.text))
```

The output is:

```
D:\wamp\www\mysite\scrap>python scrap.py 
<select id="sayisal-tarihList" name="tarihList" onchange="tarihSecildi(this)">
</select>


D:\wamp\www\mysite\scrap>
```

Note that, if I copy the related part of the HTML via F12 (right click on the `<select>` and choose "copy outer html"), I can get the `<option>` values, however, BS can't fetch it.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: I won't click the link, but I'd bet my car that the `select` is populated via javascript. That means you need something that can execute javascript and *then* you can get the resulting html. BeautifulSoup alone won't cut it. You need something like Selenium.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks for the idea but you can click it if you like, note that the site has gov.tr domain name, means is a fully trustable government-headed site.

Comment: Ok, I clicked and it was as I suspected (so my car is safe :) ). Instead of using F12 which gives you the current state of the DOM, use "show source" or whatever it is in your browser. If you go to line 435 of the html, you'll notice that the `select` is actually empty (contains a comment, but that's irrelevant as far as your scraper is concerned).

Comment: while still in `F12` mode, take a look at the "Network" tab, you should notice the call to `http://millipiyango.gov.tr/sonuclar/listCekilisleriTarihleri.php?tur=sayisal` that's where the values seem to come from. Maybe it can be useful.

Comment: what values are you after? The list of dates in the dropdown?

Comment: any update on this?